# cant get windows7 pro to work with domain contorler (samba running on unbuntu 8.04ltr)

Tags: windows-7, domain

I just got two desktops with windows7 64bit pro.

I have the domain setup using samba but it appears that for some reason that windows 7 does not see the domain when i type in the credentials it just kicks it back saying no.

any ideas on what i can do to fix this

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Samba wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7) you'll need Samba 3.3.7 or Samba 3.4.0 for Windows 7 to be able to logon.  It also suggests there are a couple registry entries needed to be added to Windows 7 before joining the Samba domain as well.

Comment: any word if windows plans on fixing this?

Comment: It's not a Windows issue to fix, it's a Samba issue.  Perhaps Samba 3.5 won't need these registry settings, perhaps Samba 4, hard to say, especially since I'm not a Samba developer. :)